# What's the meaning of 来たこと?

Tags: meaning

Both of the following two sentences taken from two different sources contain `来たこと`. How could this `来たこと` be interpreted?

- 「来れたら行く」と言って来たことある人ってほとんどいない気がします。 ([source](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1295722152))
- これは上流から見ているので奥から進んで来たことになる。 ([source](http://www.geocities.jp/chilokulo/wek.html))

== Edit ==
Corrected the link of the second source.

Comment: My initial thought is that maybe こと is just the usual "こと as a nominalizer" usage, and that 言って来た and 進んで来た are compound verbs (くる shows up in many compounds, often to indicate "movement" towards the speaker)

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy　一文目の「言って来た」は複合動詞ではなく、「～～と言って、来た人はいない」って切れてます。（「～てくる」「～ていく」「～てくれる」等は複合動詞というより、て形+補助動詞「くる」「いく」「くれる」などの形じゃないでしょうか。一文目の例は、別の動詞ですが。）

Comment: @chocolate あ、なるほど。「、」と「が」をわかりやすくにする為に入れても、【「来れたら、行く」と言って、来た事がある人】は同じ意味ですよね。英語で、"People who say "I'll come if I am able to" and then actually show up pretty much don't exist"とはあってますか？

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy そおですね。。そんな感じだと思います(たぶん、直訳すると。) ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is 来たこと means **"the fact/matter/thing of having come"**.  It is a **"noun-ed" form of 来る**.

To the best of my knowledge there is **no special connection between 来た and こと** here (as opposed to other possible verbs).  The こと is acting as a **nominalizer** (it converts the previous verb phrase into a noun phrase:

eg 走る->走ること "(to) run"->"the matter/thing of running".

**こと** can act this way **with most verbs** and many verb tenses.  There also several other "general" nominalizers like もの and nominalizer の.

This page of Tae Kim's guide goes into more detail about the ことがある use: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/genericnouns

---

The **first** sentence can be roughly translated as

> People who say "I'll come if I am able to" and then actually show up
>   pretty much don't exist

or more loosely:

> When people say "I'll come if I am able to", they generally don't have
>   any intention of coming.

The **second** sentence is maybe along the lines of

> Here, if we were looking from upstream, it (becomes clear/appears) that
>   (you/it?) have (proceeded and) come from the inside.

with the exact translation depending on context.

[Edit: from the now-working source link we can see the context]
He is talking about the picture of the stream, which he has been following from downstream to upstream.  He is saying that if the picture was instead taken from the upstream direction, then we would be able to see how he had come from the inside (of the town, I'm guessing).

---

It might be easier to **parse the first sentence** with some extra punctuation and particles inserted explicitly as so:

> 「来れたら、行く」と言って、来たことがある人ってほとんどいない気がします。

来れたら、行く = "If (I) am able to, (I) will come."
言って、来たことがある人 = "A person who, having said that, has come"

Comment: Thank you. So `こと` here is used as a normalizer. I had corrected the link of the second source. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: As I like to say, こと　and の　can act as "noun-afiers"